# Eomonth function on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am getting an error on this function, even it is defined. What could cause this problem?

[image]

Comment: [Text as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/) started early...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EOMONTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

I suspect the [Compatibilty level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) of your database is set below that (or you are in fact not on SQL Server 2014).

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name   
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120   -- 120 == SQL Server 2014
```

To determine your SQL Server version run:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

An alternative way of calculating EOMONTH is:

```
DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Date) + 1, 0))
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error `Msg 15048, Level 16, State 1, Line 392
Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.`

Comment: then you are not on SQL Server 2014 ! If 100 is the maximum you are on 2008.

Comment: run SELECT @@VERSION

Comment: `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)`. I was looking through `help>about`.

Comment: Thank you for alternative way

Comment: There is another server, where `eomonth` is running smoothly, so I thought this one was also 2014. Sorry

Comment: The syntax highlight for `SELECT @@VERSION` looks weird. Is it supposed to be like that? Or can it be blamed on the [weird syntax highlighter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter)?

Answer (score 1):

[EOMONTH()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) returns a date type

[REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )

```
REPLACE ( EOMONTH( cast(@variable as date) )  '-','.')
```

You are attempting an implicit conversion from date to string, and it seems you are assuming that a date data type actually contains a dash, which isn't true. Just use format to the desired output. No need for replace and use a set of `DATEADD()` functions to substitute for `EOMONTH()`

```
select format(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, getDate()), 0)),'yyyy.MM.dd')
```

Comment: while that's true, it's not the answer to the problem the OP was experiencing